# Catch Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis connection fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redis, asp.net-core

I need to use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis into my asp.net core project.

I put this code into ConfigureService (Startup.cs):

```
IDistributedCache cache = new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions
{
    Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis"),
    InstanceName = "Master"
});

services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCache>(cache);
```

What I need is to catch a connection exception (in case the Redis server is down, or the server is not reachable), but I haven't found a method to check connection and if I wrap code into a try/catch nothing happens.

Is there a way to accomplish my task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this step you haven't opened a connection to Redis yet, you only created an instance of [RedisCache](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs) class.

The connection will be opened later when you will use public methods of the class. Something like `RedisCache.GetAsync` method as the example:

```
// IDistributedCache  _cache;
// ...
// This is the place where you may get the exception
var value = await _cache.GetAsync(key);
```

Here connection will  be created internally (if needed) using private [Connect](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs#L146-L162) methods.